# Linear transformations between tensor spaces

Tags: multivariable-calculus, tensors

I'm going through Spivak's calculus on manifolds, and I was wondering whether the following is a typo.

> If $f:V\rightarrow W$ is a linear transformation, a linear transformation $f^*:\mathfrak{T}^k(W)\rightarrow\mathfrak{T}^k(V)$ is defined by $$f^*T(v_1,\dots,v_k)=T(f(v_1)\dots,f(v_k))$$ for $T\in\mathfrak{T}^k(W)$ and $v_1,\dots,v_k\in V$

Surely $f^*$ should be from $\mathfrak{T}^k(V)\rightarrow\mathfrak{T}^k(W)$?  Everything he writes would seem to support this, since $T(v_1,\dots,v_k)\in\mathfrak{T}^k(V)$, but he seems to double down on it after the definition by writing "$T\in\mathfrak{T}^k(W)$".  What have I misunderstood about the space of tensors, or is this a genuine typo?

Comment: No typo. $f^*T(v_1,\dots,v_k)$ is $(f^*T)(v_1,\ldots,v_k)$, and this formula is defining $f^*T$ for any $T\in\mathfrak T^k(W)$.

Comment: I see, so it is transforming $T$ so that it can "take" $v\in V$ as inputs.  Could you write that as an answer and I'll give it a tick?